# pay from phonepe or googlePay through razorpay

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, razorpay, razorpay-andoid-sdk

How can I implement a redirect functionality from a React Native button to either PhonePe or Google Pay using Razorpay as a payment gateway?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.